# Open static HTML file from asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I need to open HTML page from my aspx page using following javascript, but it's showing blank page in chrome and firefox and nothing happen in IE9.

```
 ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "openWindow",
 "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>showModalDialog('C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/test.html');</script>");
```

Answer (score 1):

You try to open a file on the client computer

`C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/test.html`

you must distinguish the code that run on server and the code that run on client.

When you make an html page, a web page, your files and connections must get from the server using `http://` protocol. Its impossible to read a file that way from the server, its also impossible to give command to the client to read a file from his computer.

Comment: these html files are generated by a background thread in web application and resides on server. These files are physically present on server where website will reside

Comment: @MuhammadFaiqBakhtyar Ok you make them, but I see the path are on Desktop - do you save them on desktop ? Save them on IIS web site path, and then give the correct http:// path to read them from the client.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
string strScript = "window.open('C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/test.html');";
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), strScript, true);
```